# Unable to locate elements within ng-repeat-start loop using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am having trouble locating an element within an ng-repeat loop with protractor 5.2.0 (node 8.4.0, angular 1.5). 
The UI code looks something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="app in appsData.result" class="bordered"> 
<td>
<md-button id="{{app.name}}" class="md-raised primary" ng-click="appAction('configure', app)">
Configure and Run 
</md-button> 
</td>
</tr> 
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="expanded" ng-class="{'highlighted': expanded}">
```

..... 
I tried

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater("app in appsData.result"));
rows.first().element(by.tagName("button")).getText().then(function(text){
console.log("Text: "+text);
});
```

but I am getting a

> [12:24:40] E/launcher - NoSuchElementError: Index out of bound. Trying
>   to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that
>   match locator by.repeater("app in appsData.result")

(I also tried tagName = md-button)

I did a browser.getPageSource()
 but I only see

```
<tbody>
<!-- ngRepeat: app in appsData.result -->
</tbody>
```

I am fairly new to protractor, any help would be greatly appreciated!

My protractor conf file looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  getPageTimeout: 600000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 5000000,
  framework: 'custom',
  // path relative to the current config file
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--no-sandbox', 'headless']
    }
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
  specs: [
    'features/*.feature'
  ],

  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/step_definitions/*.js',
    tags: false,
    format: 'pretty',
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class="bordered" is unique, you can try:

```
var rows = element.all(by.css('[class="bordered"]'));
rows.first().element(by.css('md-button')).getText().then(function(text){
    console.log("Text: "+text);
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rows = element.all(by.css('[class="bordered"]'));
rows.first().element(by.css('md-raised.primary')).getText().then(function(text){
console.log("Text: "+text);
});
```

Also You can select by xpath or class name if this is not working:

```
element(by.className("md-raised primary"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, neither of the methods is working. I get a [12:21:54] E/launcher - Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, [class="bordered"])
[12:21:54] E/launcher - NoSuchElementError: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, [class="bordered"])